# adding index of an array to another array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a mat table with 100 columns. I want to add the column header to the table from another table. I want to make it in specific format.

Please guide me on how can I achieve this.

```
arr1 = [{corntest0: 10},{syruptest0: 20}, {coorntest1: 30}, {syruptest1: 40}, {corntest2: 50}, .... ]


ch=[{def: corntest , header: testavailable }, {def: syruptest , header: testnotavailable }....]
```

How can I add the index from `arr1` as the index of array `ch` and also add header if `def` is `corntest` then header is `testavailable`?

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `map()` function to transform your array. The indices will be preserved.

```js
let arr1 = [{corntest0: 10},{syruptest0: 20}, {coorntest1: 30}, {syruptest1: 40}, {corntest2: 50}];
let ch = arr1.map(v => {
    let key = Object.keys(v)[0];
    def = key.replace(/\d+$/, "");
    let header = def === 'corntest' ? 'testavailable' : 'testnotavailable';
    return {def, header};
});
console.log(ch);
```

Comment: I have forgot to add a details. i edited the question can you please check it. Thanks.

Comment: Updated to use `corntest0`, `syruptest0` in the input. The regex search/replace using `key.replace(/\d+$/, "")` removes the trailing number,

Comment: Could you explain what is your expected output?